# Colorblind WPF Spellcheck

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, spell-checking, color-blindness

Is there any way to use the default WPF Spellchecker to squiggly-underline misspelled words in a textbox control in a different color other than red (to, for example, yellow)?

This is a pretty important feature for our business application, as many people who use it are colorblind.

I've searched through stackoverflow, MSDN documentation, and many other sources without any success. In the end, I ended up downloading symbols and searching for how the underline is drawn, but I wasn't able to find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think of this approach using some custom `Effect`, this effect will turn some specific colors into other colors. In this case they're blind to Red, so turning Red (not just red wavy underline but even red text) into yellow. That makes sense. However writing a custom Effect is not easy, you have to know **HLSL** (High Level Shading Language). I think once you know that, implementing this kind of colors mapper is just a trifle.

Comment: Works great for most letters. Letters that overlap with the squiggly-underline cause issues though and don't get picked up by the shader constraints. It's a bit reliant on forcing the UI to be of a certain color as well, which I don't like.

Comment: I agree that the RED line is actually not totally red especially when overlapping with some letters. But it's not some kind of forcing the UI to be a certain color. The UI you apply the effect here is just ***your text box***. What if your textbox letters, background or everything (inside your textbox) appear in a RED-like (RED-close) color? All should be converted to some other color your blind user could see. That does make sense (I said this before).

Comment: For solving the issue of overlapping letters, you can try using some tolerance, the form of RGB should meet this condition: G is always equal to B (and equal to a low value from 0 to about 90), while R is normally about 150 larger than G and B. E.g: when G and B are about 0, R is about 159, when G and B are about 90, R is about 240 or more ... So it's fairly feasible. Finally I don't think there is some easy solution for you to solve this, it's some kind of hard-coded feature. Unless you may want to implement your own spell checker.